# Unable to Uninstall Python in OsX

Tags: python, python-3.x, uninstallation

I have installed python 3.9.10 in my mac machine. But when I check the version using python --version the version is found to be 3.9.7

I also tried to remove it through finder but the version there was 3.9.10

```
(base) adminuser@User-MacBook-Air ~ % brew uninstall python
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/python
(base) adminuser@User-MacBook-Air ~ % python --version
Python 3.9.7
```

I checked if there are other versions installed and I couldn't find any! Is there anything that I can do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you have anaconda installed?

Comment: Yes I have installed conda!

Comment: The command `python --version` would be hitting your anaconda installation in that case

Comment: Can I continue installing python packages with this version itself or is there anything else that I have to do?

Comment: You are in activated venv, notice the `(base)` at the beginning at the line. You can deactivate your venv and look for your system python or make another venv to use, or whatever you want

Comment: You'll need to use conda commands to install packages. https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/install-packages/